# ValueError at /admin/services/blog/add/blog objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to create a blog by the admin panell. but i'm not able to save. Can you please help. Model.py

```
class blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    blog_category_name=models.ForeignKey(blog_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    blog_sub_category_name=models.ForeignKey(blog_sub_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    written_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='sandeep')
    image_banner= models.ImageField(upload_to='image_banner')
    medium_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='medium_thumbnail')
    content = RichTextField() # RichTextField is used for paragraphs
    is_authentic=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta: # Plurizing the class name explicitly
        verbose_name_plural = 'blog'
     
    def __str__(self): # Dundar Method
        return self.blog_title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Saving Modefied Changes
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.blog_title)
```

For some reason when I'm trying to save the tags and the data I'm getting this error

Comment: Please remember to include the versions you're using of python, django, and (though it may not always be applicable) OS.

Additionally, please remember to include any import statements to have your posted code snipping be functional.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot call the super method in `save`. Then when django tries to save the related objects, the blog object has not been saved yet.

```py
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Saving Modefied Changes
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.blog_title)
        super(blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```